# Using jPages with content delivered via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-pagination

I'm having some real issue getting the jPages (http://luis-almeida.github.io/jPages/) plugin to work with content delivered via ajax.

The page I am building essentially allows the user to view a list of current vacancies that are available at our client's company. Upon loading the page, an ajax request is fired using the default values in a form. This request then returns all vacancies to the page (see below).

This is great when we have a small number of vacancies as shown below however, what if we have 100's of vacancies?

[image: All Vacancies]

To counteract this issue, I have decided to use jPages to paginate the results of the ajax request that is sent on page load. Firstly, the default structure of my base html for this page (where the content is loaded into) is as follows:

```
<div class="icams-specific" id="icams-specific">
  <h1>Vacancies</h1>
  <h2><span class="numberFound">&nbsp;</span> found - <a class="inline-job-alerts" href="/job-alerts.html">set up alerts</a></h2>
  <hr />
  <div id="searchContentWindow"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see, it's a very simple structure. When my ajax is loaded the first time round, this html becomes:

```
<div class="icams-specific" id="icams-specific">
  <h1>Vacancies</h1>
  <h2><span class="numberFound">&nbsp;</span> found - <a class="inline-job-alerts" href="/job-alerts.html">set up alerts</a></h2>
  <hr />
  <div id="searchContentWindow">
    <div class="jobpost Job Postings">
      <div class="template_image"></div>
      <div class="jobpost_body">
        <h2><a href="/vacancy/it-consultant-176602.html">IT Consultant</a></h2>
        <p>To carry out a range of assigned clerical/support duties in accordance with predetermined procedures and service standards under appropriate guidance and direction.</p>
        <p>
          <span class="jobclass even department">
            <span class="jobclass_type">Department:</span>
            <span class="jobvalue">Engineering</span>&nbsp;
          </span>
          <span class="jobclass uneven location">
            <span class="jobclass_type">Location:</span>
            <span class="jobvalue">Farnborough</span>&nbsp;
          </span>
          <span class="jobclass even refno">
            <span class="jobclass_type">Ref No:</span>&nbsp;2&nbsp;
          </span>
        </p>
     </div> <!-- end of jobpost_body -->
     <div class="jobpost_nav">
        <p><a title="View this vacancy or apply &gt; (IT Consultant)" href="#" class="apply_direct">View this vacancy or apply &gt;</a>
           <a title="Send a friend (IT Consultant)" class="send_a_friend" href="#">Send a friend</a>
        </p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="divider">
     <hr>
   </div>
</div>
```

This structure is repeated over and over for each vacancy. The function I use to make this call is as follows:

```
function fireAjaxRequest(formUrl,contentArea,form){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: formUrl,
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function(response){
      var errorMessageFound = $(response).find('p.error');
      var numberOfRoles = 0;
      if(errorMessageFound.length > 0){
        contentArea.html(errorMessageFound);
        $('.numberFound').html(numberOfRoles + ' job');
      }else{
        var filteredSearch = $(response).find('div.searchresults:last');        
        var numberOfRolesCalc = $(filteredSearch).find('.jobpost').each(function(){
          numberOfRoles++;
        });
        contentArea.html(filteredSearch);
        if(numberOfRoles > 1){
          var jobs = '&nbsp;jobs';
        }else{
          var jobs = '&nbsp;job';
        }
        $('.numberFound').html(numberOfRoles + jobs);
        form.find('#p_text').val('');
        trimSpacing();
      }             
     }
    });
   }
```

As part of trying to implement jPages into this setup, I have add the following to the end of this code:

```
...trimSpacing();
$('.searchresults').attr('id', 'searchResults');
$('div.holder').jPages({
  containerID : 'searchResults'
  ,perPage : 2
});...
```

This works in a way as the pagination kicks in however, it oddly seems to group the following html into separate pages:

```
<div class="jobpost Job Postings" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">...</div>
<div class="divider" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">...</div>
```

The content, and the divider. I believe it is doing this as it is applying the perPage to each div within the specified container where really is should only apply this to divs with a class of .jobpost .

I've looked through the documentation for this plugin but cannot find a way of specifying which elements should be specifically paginated. Ideally, this script should be showing as 2 jobs per page but it is actually showing 1 because of the divider div.

Does anyone have any suggestions or workarounds that could be put in place to ensure that the right number of jobs are shown per page? Is there the ability to specify a selector to break on that is not in the documentation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The page in question can be found here (http://equiniti.hireserve-projects.com/vacancies.html) and is a work in progress.

If you require any further information or code, please don't hesitate to ask.

Jezzipin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I have found so far is to parse the filteredSearch variable before is output to the page using the following code:

```
$(filteredSearch).find('.divider').each(function(){
   $(this).remove();
});
```

However, if there is an alternative method that would be better in this situation that avoids removing content from the ajax response, I'm open to suggestions.